# combining date and time columns for query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a database table with separate date and time column. To get particular I execute query in mysql in following manner

```
select * from table_A where empID='A1201' order by TIMESTAMP(date,time) desc limit 1
```

How can I convert this particular for codeigniter? I tried in following manner but it's not working

```
$column = 'TIMESTAMP(date,time)';
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('empID', 'A1201');
$this->db->from('table_A');
$this->db->order_by($column, 'desc');
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get();
$data = $query->result();
return $data;
```

This query result in error since it executes in following manner `ORDER BY TIMESTAMP(date DESC, time) DESC` while the correct way is `ORDER BY TIMESTAMP(date,time) DESC`. What will be the correct way for codeigniter using active record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->where('empID', 'A1201')
    ->from('table_A')
    ->order_by($column, 'desc', false)
    ->limit(1)
    ->get();
```

order by comes with a 3rd option - just set this to `false`

> You can get more infos about that in their documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=group#CI_DB_query_builder::order_by)